# React/redux combineReducers issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I'm trying to combine two reducers with redux: increment and decrement reducers.

In my *store.js* file:

With this line `import reducer from "./reducers/increment";` the button *increment* works.

With this line `import reducer from "./reducers/decrement";` the button *decrement* works.

With this line `import reducer from "./reducers/index";` the **counter does not even display**.

My code is given [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-wescoff-ng8jx).

What am I doing wrong please ?

What if the two reducer states have the same *counter* value ? Which is the source of truth if the value of counter is modified ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a substitute example for your real code, but I would recommend combining the actions into one reducer, called `counter` so that there is one source for the current `counter` state.

You should do this because in your `mapStateToProps` function inside `SiblingTwo.js`, you need to do:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    counter: state.increment.counter
});
```

It's either `state.increment.counter` or `state.decrement.counter`, so it only makes sense to combine the reducers into one originally and call `state.counter.counter`.

Your current code is not working because you are incorrectly calling `counter: state.counter`